Can beliefs equal Knowledge?
Do you think that beliefs can equal Knowledge?
If beliefs are never caused by themselves and if we understand knowledge to be what guides us throw our daily lives, instead of an absolute truth, could the answer for the question be yes?

if we understand knowledge to be what guides us throw our daily lives, instead of an absolute truth So you're suggesting there can be knowledge that is not absolutely true?  I am confused by your terminology.

No. If we understand "sky" to be grass then it will be green, but we already have "grass" for that. What guides us through our daily lives can be a lot of things even aside from beliefs, instincts, emotions, intuitions, etc., but why call all of that "knowledge" when the word is already used for something else? Even so-called lightweight knowledge requires true belief. We wouldn't want to muddy the language and start saying that we no longer "know" what we "knew" when what guides us turns out to be wrong, as it often does.

Just dropping this here because we don't have another place to put it: a good article on the history of skepticism. (It really helps when the professor is also a Hugo nominated author): https://www.exurbe.com/sketches-of-a-history-of-skepticism-part-i-classical-eudaimonia/

This is a question about how we define beliefs, knowledge, and absolute truth. Here are the usual definitions in philosophy:

A belief is any proposition you think is true. You may have a good, justified reason for thinking that, or you might not. Belief in God, belief in gravity, belief that lizard people are controlling the government, belief that 2+2=4, belief that you are wearing a plaid shirt - these are all defined as "beliefs."
Knowledge is a kind of belief. Everything you know is something you believe, but not everything you believe is something you know. Exactly what separates knowledge from other beliefs is a matter of debate, but generally we say knowledge should at least be true, and it should be justified in our minds, and the justification shouldn't rely on false assumptions.
But either way, we shouldn't speak of beliefs as distinct from knowledge; knowledge is a subset of beliefs.
What defines "truth" is also a matter of debate, but for at least some propositions we can say that they are true if they describe a state of affairs that actually exists in the world. "I am wearing a hat" is true if and only if I am wearing a hat. So, some of our beliefs are true, and others are false. Of those that are true, some of them are knowledge, and some are not.

